# Which symbol matches "underline" in Regex in Js

Tags: javascript, regex, underline

```
str = "The stor-+)_y is someth12ing that tr@#ee3 de124scrib%^&ing 
becom5es life7 4 difficult";
console.log(str.replace(/\W/g,''));
```

Guys, have written this RegEx for matching all non alphanumeric characters, but cannot select 'underline' ? 
As I know, \d is for all digits
            \s for whitespace... so, what letter stand for underline?

Comment: Do you mean `/[\W_]/g`?

Comment: *"what letter stand for underline"* No letter stands for underline, underlining is a font effect. If you're asking what character matches an *underscore*, it's...an underscore: `_`.

Comment: And the char you need is called an *underscore*, not *underline*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match all non-alphanumeric characters, `\W` is not enough since matches the same text as `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` does. To match `_` with your regex, add `_` and `\W` to a character class:

```js
str = "The stor-+)_y is someth12ing that tr@#ee3 de124scrib%^&ing becom5es life7 4 difficult";
console.log(str.replace(/[\W_]+/g,''));
```

Since you are removing, it is advisable to quantify with `+` (to remove 1+ consecutive occureences in one go).

Comment: Got it, it is working like this; But can you explain why we use [] and _ after \W ? Is it same like , if we want to add to digits '\d' then adding by "_" it means all digits and underline?

Comment: `[...]` form a *character class* (or *bracket expression*) that matches a single character defined in the class. `[\d_.]+` matches one or more digits, `.` or/and `_`. You may read more about [*character classes* here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).